# I am getting the following php error

Tags: php

This is the part of my code giving the problem.I tried to use isset but i think my syntax is incorrect. I still get the Notice: Undefined index: id.

```
if($_GET['id'] && $record['allusers'] != "Y"){
        $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE alljobs = 'Y'");
        while($arr2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2)){
            $userjobs2[] = $arr2['id']; 
        }
```

Comment: I don't see where you are using `isset()`.

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['id']) &&`

Comment: It seems your $_GET["id"] is not exists. Create a check, is that key exists.

   `if (isset($_GET["id"]) ...`

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct this is not an `Error` it is a `Notice` to get rid of this you can use `isset($_GET['id'])`

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $record['allusers'] != "Y"){
        $q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE alljobs = 'Y'");
        while($arr2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2)){
            $userjobs2[] = $arr2['id']; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['id']` won't return boolean. It will throw error if undefined/unset. Use isset().

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $record['allusers'] != 'Y') {
    // code...
}
```